# how to set ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES in GlassFish 3.1.1?

Tags: linux, glassfish

I'm running GlassFish 3.1.1 on Linux and in my server.log I've noticed the following error:

```
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR log4j called after unloading, see
     http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#unload.
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class invariant violation
```

Looking at the URL provided, it suggests to "Set the org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES system property to false."

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer: from the shell, inside the GlassFish directory with GlassFish running, type:

```
bin/asadmin create-system-properties  \
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
```

I've added the backslash to format the command in two lines, but it can be typed without it on one line.

Answer (score 0):

Minor improvement.
If the domain is not using the default port 4848, you can do as follow :

```
bash-3.2$ ./asadmin --port 9048 create-system-properties  org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
Command create-system-properties executed successfully.
```